# File download in IE10

Tags: vba, excel, automation, download, internet-explorer-10

I'm working on an internet explorer automation project. The code downloads and saves a file from a website. Its possible to download and save file using 'SendKeys' but its not a reliable method as I cannot detect the download notification:

[image: The notification which is currently undedectable]

Is there a way to download and save the file without 'SendKeys'? or at least is there a way to detect the presence of this notification?

Ps - I have referred to these links, which are helpful for IE8 downloads:

- http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/23/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window/
- http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/02/02/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window-part-ii/

Any help?

Comment: You should post your existing code with the SendKeys method you attempted for better help.

Comment: We can look at this code for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472310/dealing-with-the-open-save-cancel-dialogue-window-in-ie-when-using-vba

Comment: Refer this might be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038165/automate-saveas-dialouge-for-ie9-vba/26737718?noredirect=1#comment42639525_26737718

Comment: @Lifewithsun - I have not tried it yet. It looks like this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you know the full URL of the file that you are downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to use `SendKeys` method to download a file? Sorry, this is wrong approach.
Use API!

**Solution 1:**

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
  "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
    szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long


Sub DownloadFilefromWeb()
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim URL As String, ext As String
    Dim buf, ret As Long
    URL = Worksheets("References & Resources").Range("URLMSL").Value
    buf = Split(URL, ".")
    ext = buf(UBound(buf))
    strSavePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "DownloadedFile." & ext
    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
    If ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Download has been succeed!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Source: [VBA - Save a file from a Website](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/67123-visual-basic-applications-save-file-website.html)

**Solution 2:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DownloadXLFileFromURL()

    Dim myURL As String, sFilename As String
    myURL = "http://img.chandoo.org/hw/max-change-problem.xlsx"
    sFilename = Environ("SystemDrive") & Environ("HomePath") & _
            Application.PathSeparator & "Desktop" & Application.PathSeparator & _
            "file.xlsx"

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False ', "username", "password"
   WinHttpReq.Send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile sFilename, 2  ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
       oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Source: [Download file from URL using VBA](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/download-file-from-url-using-vba.15636/)

**Solution 3:**

Finally, you can create custom class, which can create an instance of MS IE. Now, you are able to control/manage of IE object via using its properties and events, such as [DownloadBegin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768330%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [DownloadComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FileDownload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Please, see: [Using the WebBrowser Control from Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Note: Never before i tried it...